# Деструктуризация обьектов

Tags: javascript

Как поменять в массиве с обьектами поле unread c false на true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов много, через map можно так думаю

```js
let array = [{id:1, unread: false},{id:2, unread: false},{id:3, unread: true}]

console.log(array);

let array1 =array.map(item=> { item.unread = true; return item; });
 
console.log(array1);
```

можно через reduce

```js
let array = [{id:1, unread: false},{id:2, unread: false},{id:3, unread: true}]

console.log(array);

let array1 =array.reduce((acc, item)=> { item.unread = true; acc.push(item); return acc; }, []);

console.log(array1);
```

или так как вы хотели

```js
let array = [{id:1, unread: false},{id:2, unread: false},{id:3, unread: true}]

let array1 =array.map(item => ({...item, unread:true}));

console.log(array1);
```

По просьбе @UModeL добавил всякого мягкого для развития на скорую руку

```js
let array = [{id:1, unread: false},{id:2, unread: false},{id:3, unread: true}]

let array1 =array.map(item => ({...item, unread: !item.unread}));

console.log(array1);

let array2 =array.map(item => ({...item, unread: { anyData: Math.random(), unread: item.id + ' ' + item.unread}}));

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: map больше нравится - почему сразу не догалался незнаю. Я питался сделать через for in

Comment: А сильно увеличится код, если *unread* помимо *false* мог бы иметь и другие значения?

Comment: @UModeL не понятно к чему вы? Думаю измениться на не очень много

Comment: @AzizUmarov: чисто для саморазвития. Я просто увидел, что Вы быстро и чётко ответили, ну и решил поинтересоваться. Думал, может добавите вариант.

Comment: @UModeL, а что именно под другими значениями вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @AzizUmarov: да, любое другое - null, undefined, строка... Просто чтобы был третий вариант значения (булево то только два значения имеет :)

Comment: @AzizUmarov: ага! Премного благодарствую.